# Spring Boot Maven - Unable to package Web app as executable jar/war

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I'm trying to learn how to build a Web App using Spring Boot and MVC.

I'm able to create a Spring boot application, and run it from my Eclipse by executing the main method in my `SpringBootWebApplication` class. It works fine and I'm able to launch my application by hitting `http://localhost:8080`.

Now, I want to package my application as an executable WAR or JAR (I don't know which one is right!). To do this, I added a build plugin called `spring-boot-maven-plugin` in my `pom.xml`

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>org.sriram</groupId>
    <artifactId>springboot</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>springboot Maven Webapp</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.1.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- Web -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Tomcat Embed -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- JSTL -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- To compile JSP files -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>


    <build>
        <plugins>
            <!-- Package as an executable jar/war -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

For the record, I created this pom based on the tutorial [here](https://www.mkyong.com/spring-boot/spring-boot-hello-world-example-jsp/)

When I run `mvn clean package -e` from my Command prompt, I get an error like the one below:

```
[INFO] Error stacktraces are turned on.
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building springboot Maven Webapp 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[WARNING] The POM for org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:jar:1.5.1.RELEASE is invalid, transitive dependencies (if any) will not be available, enable debug logging for more details
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 0.890 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2017-08-01T13:03:42+05:30
[INFO] Final Memory: 8M/184M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Plugin org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:1.5.1.RELEASE or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:jar:1.5.1.RELEASE: 1 problem was encountered while building the effective model for org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:[unknown-version]
[ERROR] [FATAL] Non-parseable POM C:\Users\Sriram\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-parent\1.5.1.RELEASE\spring-boot-parent-1.5.1.RELEASE.pom: in epilog non whitespace content is not allowed but got r (position: END_TAG seen ...</profiles>\n</project>\nr... @946:2)  @ C:\Users\Sriram\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-parent\1.5.1.RELEASE\spring-boot-parent-1.5.1.RELEASE.pom, line 946, column 2
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.plugin.PluginResolutionException: Plugin org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:1.5.1.RELEASE or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:jar:1.5.1.RELEASE
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.internal.DefaultPluginDependenciesResolver.resolve(DefaultPluginDependenciesResolver.java:117)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.internal.DefaultMavenPluginManager.getPluginDescriptor(DefaultMavenPluginManager.java:181)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.internal.DefaultMavenPluginManager.getMojoDescriptor(DefaultMavenPluginManager.java:286)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.getMojoDescriptor(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:241)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.DefaultLifecycleMappingDelegate.calculateLifecycleMappings(DefaultLifecycleMappingDelegate.java:110)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.DefaultLifecycleExecutionPlanCalculator.calculateLifecycleMappings(DefaultLifecycleExecutionPlanCalculator.java:266)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.DefaultLifecycleExecutionPlanCalculator.calculateMojoExecutions(DefaultLifecycleExecutionPlanCalculator.java:217)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.DefaultLifecycleExecutionPlanCalculator.calculateExecutionPlan(DefaultLifecycleExecutionPlanCalculator.java:127)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.DefaultLifecycleExecutionPlanCalculator.calculateExecutionPlan(DefaultLifecycleExecutionPlanCalculator.java:145)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.BuilderCommon.resolveBuildPlan(BuilderCommon.java:96)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:110)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:309)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:194)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:107)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:993)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:345)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:191)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: org.eclipse.aether.resolution.ArtifactDescriptorException: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:jar:1.5.1.RELEASE
        at org.apache.maven.repository.internal.DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.loadPom(DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.java:339)
        at org.apache.maven.repository.internal.DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.readArtifactDescriptor(DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.java:199)
        at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultRepositorySystem.readArtifactDescriptor(DefaultRepositorySystem.java:296)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.internal.DefaultPluginDependenciesResolver.resolve(DefaultPluginDependenciesResolver.java:103)
        ... 27 more
Caused by: org.apache.maven.model.building.ModelBuildingException: 1 problem was encountered while building the effective model for org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:[unknown-version]
[FATAL] Non-parseable POM C:\Users\Sriram\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-parent\1.5.1.RELEASE\spring-boot-parent-1.5.1.RELEASE.pom: in epilog non whitespace content is not allowed but got r (position: END_TAG seen ...</profiles>\n</project>\nr... @946:2)  @ C:\Users\Sriram\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-parent\1.5.1.RELEASE\spring-boot-parent-1.5.1.RELEASE.pom, line 946, column 2

        at org.apache.maven.model.building.DefaultModelProblemCollector.newModelBuildingException(DefaultModelProblemCollector.java:197)
        at org.apache.maven.model.building.DefaultModelBuilder.readModel(DefaultModelBuilder.java:581)
        at org.apache.maven.model.building.DefaultModelBuilder.readParentExternally(DefaultModelBuilder.java:1097)
        at org.apache.maven.model.building.DefaultModelBuilder.readParent(DefaultModelBuilder.java:829)
        at org.apache.maven.model.building.DefaultModelBuilder.build(DefaultModelBuilder.java:331)
        at org.apache.maven.repository.internal.DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.loadPom(DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.java:321)
        ... 30 more
[ERROR]
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginResolutionException
```

I do not get any compilation errors from within my source. Given that my application is able to start up when I run the main method from within eclipse, why is my maven packaging not working? I could figure out the following:

Based on the stacktrace, I opened up the file **C:\Users\Sriram.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-parent\1.5.1.RELEASE\spring-boot-parent-1.5.1.RELEASE.pom** using Notepad++, and it did have some errors - I mean the XML seemed to be malformed and Notepad++ too threw a parse error.

While I can figure out this is the problem, I'mm not sure how the XML ended up as corrupt while it was automatically set up by my Maven pom.
What am I missing?

Thanks,
Sriram

Comment: try to remove it from your local repository and try again

Comment: Okay, as I said in my question about the malformed spring-boot-parent-1.5.1.RELEASE.pom file, it turns out that there was some content at the end of the XML document which was unparseable. I removed that extra content from the POM and saved it, and the package was successful.

What I do not understand though, is that how could the POM end up as malformed in the first place? Could this be a network issue or something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have (at least) two things to correct.

The first : your maven build fails :

> [FATAL] Non-parseable POM
>   C:\Users\Sriram.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-parent\1.5.1.RELEASE\spring-boot-parent-1.5.1.RELEASE.pom:
>   in epilog non whitespace content is not allowed but got r (position:
>   END_TAG seen ...\n\nr... @946:2)  @
>   C:\Users\Sriram.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-parent\1.5.1.RELEASE\spring-boot-parent-1.5.1.RELEASE.pom,
>   line 946, column 2

The cause is not your actual pom but the `spring-boot-parent-1.5.1.RELEASE.pom` dependency that seems corrupted.
So, first delete the `C:\Users\Sriram.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-parent\1.5.1.RELEASE\` folder and relaunch the build to download it.

Second problem : to create a executable jar or war, you have to use the 
`spring-boot:repackage` goal.

From the [plugin documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/maven-plugin/usage.html) :

> repackage: create a jar or war file that is auto-executable. It can
>   replace the regular artifact or can be attached to the build lifecycle
>   with a separate classifier.

In your pom you don't specify the `repackage` goal.
You specify just the `spring-boot-maven-plugin`:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <!-- Package as an executable jar/war -->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

So replace it by :

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <!-- Package as an executable jar/war -->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>           
            <executions>
               <execution>
                <goals>
                   <goal>repackage</goal>
                </goals>
              </execution>
           </executions>
        </plugin>
   </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: Ah. Can you explain please ?

Comment: in all my projects I do not specify the goal and I can package them, check the spring.io guide for spring boot, the goal is not required

Comment: Ok. But in your projects, do you create autoexecutable jar/war or only war that are deployed on an existing instance of Tomcat ?